# animation player on autoplay

Tags: animation

the animation player starts playing every other click
no longer under my control
have been researching solutions but have not found any answer
even default start up general evey other click the animation player starts stops
so it not the file
it makes blender unusable
have searched blender manual and tried contol f11
space bar  esc
esc does stop it but another click and it just starts running again so does not resolve the issue

help

Comment: what is the shortcut for the play action? In Preferences >Keymap > Name, and type Play and Frames > Play Animation

Comment: nevermind...found the load factory setting and it cleaned it up. thank goodness.  have a kitten here who walks across the keyboard at times ...creating things i never have found solutions..